How to change the color of a shapefile layer in Django Admin's Leaflet map based on a field's value?
I'm working on a GeoDjango project where I'm displaying a shapefile layer in a Leaflet map embedded in the Django Admin interface. I need to dynamically color the geometry (geom field) in the map based on the value of another field in the model called mean_ctrl. Django Admin with Geom Field
Here’s the color scheme I want to implement:
def get_color(mean_ctrl):
    if mean_ctrl < 60:
        return "#38A800"
    elif 60.1 <= mean_ctrl <= 120:
        return "#55FF00"
    elif 120.1 <= mean_ctrl <= 170:
        return "#FFFF00"
    elif 170.1 <= mean_ctrl <= 220:
        return "#FFAA00"
    elif 220.1 <= mean_ctrl <= 270:
        return "#FF0000"
    else:
        return "#C500FF"

I am looking for guidance on how to apply this color scheme to the Geom field on the Leaflet map in Django admin. Any guidance would be very helpful! Thank you.
